# An error occurred while running subprocess native-run

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3, native

I am new to IONIC. I am learning it.
I am trying to run the ionic app for android but it gives me below error.

[image]

Build is successful but an error occurred while running subprocess native-run.
If i run the ionic app for browser, then it's okay. No error happens

**Update my IONIC version to 5.4.9

And Platform-Tools to 29.0.5**

Error change:

> [native-run] No hardware devices found, attempting emulator...
>   [native-run] Selected emulator emulator-5554
>   [native-run]Installing
>   platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk...
>   [native-run] ERR_UNKNOWN: Non-zero exit code from adb: 1
>   [ERROR]An error occurred while running subprocess native-run.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Device offline...There's no device connected to your computer or you have not enabled debugging on your device.
If you are not running it on a device run the command ionic cordova run android --emulator
Ensure you have an emulator in your android sdk.

Comment: I used command `ionic cordova run android`. I am running app in emulator and after that this error occur.

Comment: For me, building a sample app inside Android Studio and running it solved the problem. You can use cordova command once it runs successfully on Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

some times you may not activated the developer mode on your device.

Comment: To be more precise, check the Android developer pages, how to activate the dev mode, if not done, yet. https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options

Answer (score 0):

**After a long time able to find the solution:**

You need to put the google-services.json file in the root of your project directory.

Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

make sure native-run has access to both Android SDK and AVD Home, it will not run if it can't find both:

```
$native-run android --sdk-info
SDK Location:         /home/<username>/Android/Sdk
AVD Home:             /home/<username>/.android/avd

API Level:            28
Packages:             Android SDK Platform 28  platforms;android-28  6
(!) Missing Packages: Android Emulator  emulator  
                      Google Play Intel x86 Atom System Image  system-images;android-28;google_apis_playstore;x86  /.+/


Tools:

Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3  build-tools;28.0.3  28.0.3
Android SDK Platform-Tools  platform-tools  29.0.6
Android SDK Tools 26.1.1  tools  26.1.1
```

If AVD Home is missing you should be able to just create an empty avd folder to make native-run happy:

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.android/avd
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is for Ionic application**

For anyone out there still looking for an answer.. like I was!
I tried so many options and answers on the web but they didn't work. Finally learnt that there may be many reasons for this but in my case it was likely something was corrupted in my AVD. I have ionic app and I solved this problem by

1. deleting all of the virtual devices (AVD Manager)
2. uninstall the APIs I have from SDK Manager
3. Go to your project directory and run (this is different for you if you use capacitor):

   cordova platform remove android
4. restart PC
5. reinstall (this is probably not necessary for everyone)
6. Read this page and verify your android studio has all **required** packages or tools installed https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update
7. cordova platform prepare android
8. ionic build
9. ionic cordova run android

This is what you should see (man, so good to see this!):

> Built the following apk(s):
> C:\tech\mobile-app-dev\budgetLenz\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
> native-run.cmd android --app platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
> [native-run] No hardware devices found, attempting emulator...
> [native-run] Selected emulator emulator-5554 [native-run] Installing
> platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk...
> [native-run] Starting application activity
> com.selectsapphire.budgetlenz/com.selectsapphire.budgetlenz.MainActivity...
> [native-run] Run Successful

Answer (score 0):

For me works this.

```
ionic cordova platform rm android   
ionic cordova platform add android    
npm i -g cordova-res    
ionic cordova resources android --force
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed `npm i -g cordova-res` and then `ionic cordova resources android --force` and finally `ionic cordova run android` and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Even I was facing same issue when running the application on emulator. It was working fine when running on Real device. As I read in few place it could be due to the limited storage available in the device. So I cleared the memory of the emulator and it worked fine. Below is the process, how you can remove the memory of emulator.

1. Open Android Studio and click on AVD manager.
2. Right click on the emulator on which you want to run the application and click on wipe data.
3. Now run the application again from Ionic by executing command `ionic cordova run android` then everything should work fine.